# How to switch to a different view in angular JS on click?

Tags: angularjs

Hello I was wondering how I would go about switching to a different view on user click in a dropdown menu?

When I select the "Canny" option in the dropdown, everything at and above the dropdown menu stays the same. The part below it are filled with things related to the Canny and displayed as such.

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

      <div class="container">                 <!-- top intro part -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/"> OPENCV 3.0.0</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="row"> <!-- Dropdown menu  -->
      <div class="col-md-20">
    <div id="main">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Filter List:</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <select class="form-control" 
              ng-options="filter for filter in filters" 
              ng-model="filter"
              ng-change="GoToOpenCVpage(filter)">
        <option value=""> Select Filter</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id = "content"> <!-- stuff showing opencv filter goes in here -->

    </div>

    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

the angularJS

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

/*app.factory("API", function($http) {
  return {
  getFilters: function(callback) {
  $http.get("filters.php").success(callback);
  }
  }
  });*/

app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {
    $scope.ListOfOpenCV = {};         // declare array
    // $scope.ListOfOpenCV.filter = "";  

    $scope.filters = ["Canny", "Sobel"];
    //$scope.ListOfOpenCV.filter = $scope.filters[0];

    $scope.GoToOpenCVpage = function(filter){

        if(filter === "Canny"){
            window.open("pages/MakeGray.html", "_blank", "height = 400, width = 700");

        }
    };

});
```

Currently I have it opening a new window and going to google.com the page's name is Canny.html in my folder containing all the source code.

Comment: You should include the key code in your post, rather than in a third party site

Comment: I'm sorry! When I copy paste it in, it comes out all unformatted.

Comment: Select it and hit Ctrl-K. Or press the code toolbar button, which looks like `{}`.